# How to get camera.git or gallery.git from https://android.googlesource.com?

Tags: git, android-source

I just spent the last 4 - 5 hours trying to get the source codes for the android apps (Camera or Gallery). I found posts which states that they are found here: https://android.googlesource.com.
Being new to git, I followed the instructions from some websites and used:

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Camera
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery
```

But I kept getting "fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly"

I don't understand. I found a question here in Stackoverflow to get Browser using git clone, which worked for me. But, I just can't get Camera and Gallery.

Any ideas?

Comment: Works for me. If having the whole repository isn't necessary, you could download a snapshot of the repository from the web interface instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download them without Git. Try these:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Camera/+archive/master.tar.gz
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery/+archive/master.tar.gz

Basically, you can use for any google git with following pattern.

```
https://android.googlesource.com/<google-git-unique-id>/+archive/master.tar.gz
```

Comment: U guys are fantastic!!! Arrgghh...I could have saved myself lots of angst by posting my question much earlier here. Having learned my lesson, what's the easiest way to import/ open these projects in eclipse?

Comment: Use File > Import and select General > Existing Projects into Workspace. Click next and then browse to the directory contain the project directory.

Answer (score 1):

I just copied your commands and it worked fine for me, so it must be something wrong with your install of git, or some weird network connection issue.

You might want to try completely removing git and all of its configuration files (or just reset the configuration files), and see if that works. You might also want to check if you can access [Camera](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Camera) properly from your web browser to see if you can actually connect to the server.

Comment: Thanks for answering!!! I'm using git-gui. I took the easy way out by accessing directly with web browser using http. It worked! I could have saved myself hours

Answer (score 1):

I've just tested your git clone command just now, and it works fine, which suggests to me that you have a connectivity problem, rather than a git problem.  But you said you were able to clone Browser, which confuses me.  Have you tried cloning them in a separate directory, or from a separate machine, just to rule those out?  And is your connectivity reliable, or is it potentially going up and down (I doubt this is the problem, but you never know).

Comment: How do I check if my connectivity is reliable?

Comment: Without knowing your environment, I can't be 100% sure, but I'd start by simple things like making sure you can see Google and the like.  Are you sure you managed to clone Browser and could not clone the other two?  I ask merely because it's very odd if that is the case.